# cmake add external library without a separate CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm having the following project structure in a C++ project. I am depending on an external library (`libA` as for the following) and I'm cloning the external library into the include folder using a shell script.

```
include/
  libA
    src/
      source.c
    lib/
      include/ 
    libA.a

src/
  fileA.cpp
  main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

The command given to compile the program is

```
clang -I include/libA/lib/include main.cpp fileA.cpp include/libA/src/source.c include/libA/src/libA.a
```

I have seen on stackoverflow that in order to add this external library I have to create a separate `CMakeLists.txt` in the external library folder and use `add_library()`. And in the main `CMakeLists.txt` file use `add_subdirectory()`.
Is there a way to do this without a seperate CMakeLists.txt.
My current main CMakeLists.txt file. (This works but I think I'm missing something)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.3)

project(test)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp src/fileA.cpp include/libA/src/source.c )

include_directories(include/libA/lib/include)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} /include/libA/libA.a )

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC include/libA/lib/include)
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've done, especially if it works

Comment: I'd wrap everything with the cmake module/config and use `find_package` but that's certainly not required. As Alan said: if it works for you then it's fine. If/when it isn't fine anymore you will change it to something else.

Comment: Why not create separate `CMakeLists.txt` by the way? Your project structure now is... surprising.

Comment: "I have seen on stackoverflow that in order to add this external library I have to create a separate `CMakeLists.txt` in the external library folder and use `add_library()`." - No, you haven't to create separate `CMakeLists.txt`,  you could call `add_library()` in the **current one**. In CMake creation of several `CMakeLists.txt` (in different directories) is purely structuring feature, like creating several `.c` files for a single library/executable. Like you could put all your C code into single `.c` file, you could put all your CMake code into single `CMakeLists.txt`.